# Import-SPWeb Into Host Named Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, site-collection, spweb, host-named

I have made a backup of a SharePoint Site using Export-SPWeb. I have also added a new Host Named Site Collection and I would like to Import the Site into this newly created Host Named Site Collection.

I have managed to import it into a SubSite of another Site Collection but when I try with the Host Named Site Collection it gives the following error:

`Import-SPWeb : Cannot find an SPWeb object with Id or Url :
http://demo.[companyname].com.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-SPWeb http://demo.[companyname].com -Path
C:\Import\Backup\SiteBackup\20160524\F ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...CmdletImportWeb:
   SPCmdletImportWeb) [Import-SPWeb], SPCmdletPipeBindException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletImportWe`

Comment: Have you created a site at the location of your host named site collection? If not, create one first then import your web to overwrite it.

Comment: God idea, let me try that! Thanks for you assistance

Comment: Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Yup, there is a site there as well. I also tried using a site collection backup but then it says Version String Too Long Or Too Short

Comment: What account are you running PowerShell as? Make sure the account that's being used has DBOwner permissions to the content database. Try a `Get-SPWeb`.

Comment: Account has those specific rights as well. It seems something technical as well, because it doesnt seem like many people have the issue: Restore-SPSite: Version String was too long or too short

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it right somehow. Seems when I was trying to restore it using a SiteCollectionBackup it gave an error:

```
Restore-SPSite: Version String portion was too long or too short.
```

When it gave that error it also deleted the Host Named Site Collection. So after when i tried to restore again using Import-SPWeb it couldn't find the URL for the HNSC because it has been deleted automatically.